# Displaying a portrait image in KML without it being rotated to landscape

Tags: image, kml, google-earth, portrait

I am trying to reference images with a greater height than width (portrait format) in KML script for Google Earth; however, the image always comes out as landscape, or rotated left 90 degrees, e.g.

```
<img id="id_photo" src="2012_01_21-dscf03.jpg" width="500"></img>
```

I've tried everything I could think of. Is there a image tag to correct this, e.g., `format="portrait"`?

Thanks, 
Walter

Comment: To geocodezip:
Problematic script:
<description><![CDATA[Waterfall in Short Canyon, Andrew, Henry, 21-JAN-12 17:00<img id="id_photo" src="2012_01_21-dscf03-Waterfall in Short Canyon, Andrew, Henry.jpg" width="500"></img><hr></hr>]]></description>

I've been able to show a portrait image using the following script: <description><img src="2012_01_21-dscf03-Waterfall in Short Canyon, Andrew, Henry.jpg" width="500"></img><hr></hr></description>

Comment: To geocodezip:

As before, a portrait image, displays as landscape in Google Earth with the script:
<description><![CDATA[Waterfall in Short Canyon, Andrew, Henry, 21-JAN-12 17:00<img id="id_photo" src="2012_01_21-dscf03-Waterfall in Short Canyon, Andrew, Henry.jpg" width="500"></img><hr></hr>]]></description>

However, this script does work: 
<description><img src="2012_01_21-dscf03-Waterfall in Short Canyon, Andrew, Henry.jpg" width="500"></img><hr></hr></description>

Does the "CDATA" tag limit the types of images that appear in Google Earth? 

Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an example of EXIF only rotation. Which GE probably doesn't honour.

Some cameras etc, 'rotate' a image so its the right way up by setting a flag in the EXIF data. The raw JPG itself, is still in the landscape format.

A display (or convert) program, should hopefilly notice this 'rotation required' flag, and rotate the image.

But Google Earth probably doesnt honor it, so you are just seeing the baseline image as its actully stored (unrotated)

Recommend trying one of the applications mentioned here:
http://jpegclub.org/losslessapps.html
(many note they have automatic correction - so should "fix" your jpg files)

Answer (score 0):

This is already an old thread, but I stumbled on the same problem. And did not find a solution for my situation. Eventually I found a way around, so I thought I'd share it here.

Basically the solution is to rotate the offending images twice, once 90° to the left and then back again.
What you had was an image with a width larger than the height, but with an orientation tag that tells an application to rotate it 90° (but Google Earth does not).
After rotating it twice it is an image with width and height switched, and an orientation tag that says not to rotate it. 
Now any application, including Google Earth, will display it correctly.

I used *ExifTool* to write the tags for all my images to a CSV file, created a list from that with all the pictures to rotate, and used that list to tell *IrfanView* twice to rotate them.